# angular promise delay doesn't work as expected

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

sorry i cant show full code here, i came up with the following code snippet.
I have a service and controller. 
In service, I added a 2 second timeout to my group service to test out spinner loading.

but somehow in controller, my code runs right away, without waiting for 2 seconds.

I did 3 break points, the order of execution i expected is : 2->1->3
but, it ended up with 2->3->1

Here is my service.

```
groupService.get = function() {
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    deffered.promise = $getMyDataStuffPromise.then(function (data) {
        $timeout(function() {
          deffered.resolve(); <- break point 1
        }, 2000);
    }, function (error) {
        deffered.reject();
        console.log('group error', error);
    });

    return deffered.promise; <- break point 2
};
```

controller:

```
   $q.all([
        PeopleSvc.get(),
        GroupSvc.get()
    ]).then(function(data){
           console.log('data returns, stop spinner'); <- break point 3
        });
```

could you please let me know what was wrong with this code? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deffered.promise =` is very weird (I don't know what else to call it).

But you should not even attempt to implement the [deferrred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572). [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) already returns a promise, so all you need to do here is to chain them:

```
groupService.get = function() {
    return $getMyDataStuffPromise.then(function (data) {
        return $timeout(function() {
            return undefined; // maybe data?
        }, 2000);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer of this question is: you have assigned `deferred.promise` to the wrong thing, so it doesn't work

```
groupService.get = function() {
    var deffered = $q.defer(); // deferred.promise already generated here
    /*deffered.promise = */$getMyDataStuffPromise.then(function (data) {
        $timeout(function() {
          deffered.resolve();
        }, 2000);
    }, function (error) {
        deffered.reject();
        console.log('group error', error);
    });

    return deffered.promise;
};
```

A new promise object is already generated when you call `$q.defer()`, you re-assigned it to `$getMyDataStuffPromise`, of course it would resolve earlier. Just remove the assignment will do.

And sure, move away from promise-antipattern while you can, as suggested in other post.

Comment: thank you!. that explained why the promise returned too early.